# Sending a post between servers using ONLY php

Tags: php, post, web

I have three webservers.  Two of theses have a snippit of php that needs to be run when a post request is sent in, and the third acts to send commands to the two lower servers.  I need to send a post request to the 2 lower servers using only php.  This is my current code:

```
function sendcom($sData, $sUrl){
    $params = array('http' => array(
          'method' => 'POST',
          'content' => $sData
    ));
    $ctx = stream_context_create($params);
    $fp = @fopen($sUrl, 'rb', false, $ctx);
    if (!$fp) {
        Exit;
    }
    $response = @stream_get_contents($fp);
    if ($response === false) {
        Exit;
    }
}
?>
```

First of all, why doesn't this script work when sending data to the child server.  Second of all, are there any better ways to do this (remember, I am using only php).

Comment: Stop using `@` to suppress your error messages. The functions with errors suppressed are probably the problem, and the errors you're suppressing will tell you why.

Comment: My error actually lie somewhere else in the code, but the curl method below is better than what I have currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use CURL

```
function sendcom($sData, $sUrl){
  //open connection
  $ch = curl_init();

  //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $sUrl);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $sData);

  //execute post
  curl_exec($ch);

  // Check Error
  if($errno = curl_errno($ch)) {
      $error_message = curl_strerror($errno);
      echo "cURL error ({$errno}):\n {$error_message}";
  } else {
      echo "<h2>Posted</h2>";
  }
  curl_close($ch);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Curl is what you need:

For example, I need to send some variables for send a message text to phone:

```
<?php
    $phoneNumber = '4045551111'; 
    $message = 'This message was generated by curl and php'; 
    $curlPost = 'pNUMBER='  . urlencode($phoneNumber) . '&MESSAGE=' . urlencode($message) . '&SUBMIT=Send';

    // initialize connection
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.webserver.com/sendSMS.php');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curlPost); 

    //execute post
    $data = curl_exec(); 
    curl_close($ch);
```

Or you could send data via JSON with correctly-formatted JSON data:

```
<?php
  $data = array("phoneNumber" => "4045551111", "message" => "This message was generated by curl and php");                                                                    
  $data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                   

  // initialize connection
  $ch = curl_init('http://www.webserver.com/sendSMS.php');                                                                      
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
  );                                                                                                                   

  //execute post
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
```

The `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` is purely so that the response from the remote server gets placed in `$result` rather than echoed.